# Find GCD in Q[√3] assuming it is defined

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, divisibility

How do I find the GCD of 24 and 49 in the integers of Q[√3], assuming that the GCD is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Suppose that $\alpha$ is an integer in our ring that divides $24$ and $49$. Then $\alpha$ divides $(-2)(24)+(1)(49)$.

Comment: Okay, so this was my approach: If we let d be a common divisor of 24 and 49, then, for some e,f: 24 = de, 49 = df, we get df - 2de = 1 which gives that d(f-2e) = 1 Therefore a common divisor of 24 and 49 must be a divisor of 1. But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You are finished. The only common divisors of $24$ and $49$ in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ divide $1$, that is, are units. Conversely any unit is a common divisor.  One can conclude that in our ring $1$ is a gcd of $24$ and $49$.

Comment: You are welcome. A gcd of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is by definition a ring element $\delta$ which divides both and such that any common divisor of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ divides $\delta$. In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ the gcd of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ exists unless $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both $0$. But that general fact is not needed to solve  the problem, since using $(-2)(24)+(1)(49)=1$ we can directly verify that $1$ is a gcd.